# Where does POST request go?

Tags: php, jquery, html, server

I am trying to understand the following line from a website source code:

```
$.post("/cp/gallery_items/upload_handler/", { file_name: file.name, file_size: file.size, in_element_id: "20144" } , function(data){ ... });
```

After searching many days online I can assume:

- "/cp/gallery_items/upload_handler/" - name of script that will process the request (not sure how to see the script code. When I go the the website I get a blank screen including no source script to examine)
- file_name, file_size, in_element_id - unique keys that are somewhere defined. (I tried replacing file_name with filename or file_names and request got no results).
- file_name - name of the file to be uploaded.
- the upload script returns "data", which is used later.

I have no clue where this post request is sent. I was figuring the script would somewhere mention the unique keys: file_name, file_size, in_element_id.
But I can't find it mentioned anywhere.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: `$.post` is an ajax request. Read up on how ajax works

Answer (score 3):

Great question.  You cannot see php nor post-handling code from the client-side (browser).  It is executed on the webserver and usually stored in a database.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-side_scripting

Comment: I know that can use the keys: file_name, file_size, in_element_id. How can I find out what other keys are available ?

Comment: The answer to that is in the php code that handles the request.  (The code you can't access with a browser)

Comment: I should probably add that whatever website you are posting to should provide documentation of what keys are available if it is intended to be used in that way.

Answer (score 3):

**POST** unlike GET is a request method which has data enclosed in it. POST request is a request to a server to accept the data enclosed by the body of request message. It's mainly used to store/send data to server usually files or forms data.